# Create self signed SSL certificate - nginx

Tags: nginx, ssl-certificate, openssl

I want to create a self signed SSL sertificate for my website. I will not use it for accessing the website itself but for other services i am going to be using (roundcube, phpmyadmin etc). I want to use https in these services as i am going to be exchanging sensitive data with the server. So i need the necessary key and certificate for my virtual hosts.

My question is what is the correct way to generate it. I am confused with the different suffixes crt, pem, key and i have found many different ways in the internet. The web server i am using is nginx.

Also the key how long can it be? Can it be longer than 4096 bit long?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a quick example of how easy it is :)

```
sudo mkdir /etc/nginx/ssl
cd /etc/nginx/ssl
sudo openssl genrsa -des3 -out server.key 1024
sudo openssl req -new -key server.key -out server.csr
```

--

```
You are about to be asked to enter information that will be incorporated
into your certificate request.
What you are about to enter is what is called a Distinguished Name or a DN.
There are quite a few fields but you can leave some blank
For some fields there will be a default value,
If you enter '.', the field will be left blank.
-----
Country Name (2 letter code) [AU]:US
State or Province Name (full name) [Some-State]:New York
Locality Name (eg, city) []:NYC
Organization Name (eg, company) [Internet Widgits Pty Ltd]:Awesome Inc
Organizational Unit Name (eg, section) []:Dept of Merriment
Common Name (e.g. server FQDN or YOUR name) []:example.com                  
Email Address []:
```

--

```
sudo cp server.key server.key.org
sudo openssl rsa -in server.key.org -out server.key
sudo openssl x509 -req -days 365 -in server.csr -signkey server.key -out server.crt
sudo cp /etc/nginx/sites-available/default /etc/nginx/sites-available/example
sudo nano /etc/nginx/sites-available/example
```

--

```
# HTTPS server

server {
        listen 443;
        server_name example.com;

        root /usr/share/nginx/www;
        index index.html index.htm;

        ssl on;
        ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/ssl/server.crt;
        ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/ssl/server.key; 
}
```

Comment: Thanks, it worked but can you explain the difference from doing `openssl req -x509 -nodes -days 365 -newkey rsa:2048 -keyout /etc/ssl/localcerts/privateKey.key -out /etc/ssl/localcerts/certificate.crt` ???

Comment: x509 is just you signing it and giving an expiration date ect...